# entering relative formula into a range of cells

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Essentially I have a formula to compare two values (temp calibration, context really doesn't matter). It's similar information across 5 different machines, so originally I had a formula in E23 that just said

```
=if(or(isblank(E21),isblank(E22),"",if(abs(E22-E21)>2,"FAIL","PASS"))
```

which I would flash fill to column I and everything was fine.

I'm working on VB to merge/unmerge format cells based on the number of machines were dealing with.  My issue is getting the formula to populate in the newly unmerged or remerged cells.

This is what I have so far (`r` is just a row, `allcols` returns 9):

```
For c = 0 To allcols - 5
    Dim vcel As Range
    Dim v1 As String
    Dim v2 As String
    Set vcel = xlrange(r, 5 + c)
    v1 = vcel.Offset(-2, 0).Address
    v2 = vcel.Offset(-1, 0).Address

    vcel.Formula = "=if(OR(ISBLANK(" & v1 & "),ISBLANK(" & v2 & ")),"""",IF(ABS(" & v1 & "-" & v2 & ") > 2, ""FAIL"", ""PASS""))"
Next c
```

I wish to populate `E(r):I(r)`.

This is what I tried. It's throwing me a 1004 object defined error. I'm not sure how to pursue the troubleshooting.

Comment: Which is it VBA or VBScript?  they are different.

Comment: My guess is `xlrange` should be `Cells`

Comment: The code you posted is VBA, not VBScript. Which of the two is it supposed to be? Also, please show the exact error message. Don't paraphrase.

Comment: xlrange = workbook.activesheet.cells() it is a run time 
 error 1004 --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-F1-Landing/application-defined-or-object-defined-error-office-shared-vblr6-chm1000095 I have stepped through the sub and got the error narrowed down to the vcel.formula line but ive been through it and cant find a logical or syntax error and my bad on the vbscript thing....like i said...new to this learning as i go (mechanical engineer not IT)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim s as string
 s= "=if(OR(ISBLANK(" & v1 & "),ISBLANK(" & v2 & ")),"
 s = s & Chr$(34) & chr$(34) 
 s = s & ",IF(ABS(" & v1 & "-" & v2 & ") > 2, "
 s = s & chr$(34) & "FAIL" & chr$(34) & ", " & chr$(34) 
 s = s & "PASS" & chr$(34) & "))"

 vcel.Formula =s
```

Comment: worked brilliantly.  did not know about chr(34) trick...i knew it was the " 's causing the issue but could not find a way to work around it....you a genius